# Play powerpoint video or music while using other programs at same time

Tags: ms-office, video

How can you have Powerpoint to continue to play the music or video while you are working on another program? It always stops the music or video I am showing to the audience while I click out of powerpoint and work on email while they are watching the video.

Comment: how is the powerpoint displayed on external display, with mirroring?

Comment: What version of powerpoint? iOS, Mac, or something else?

Comment: I am using PPT 2010. I use Persenter mode with Dual Screen view. On the secondary screen my class sees a video or listens to music, while I am on my main screen doing attendance or emailing a collegue. But I can't using PPT only, I have to use iTunes to play the music or Windows Media player and move it over to the Secondary screen to play so that I can use email or attendance.

Comment: Any ideas or plugins the allow powerpoint to be "persistent" on play audio/video when it is not the active program?